# Why does this utterly simple CSS code not have the desired effect?

Tags: css

I simply want to add two pictures in a row.

I use `display: inline-block;` which means my images should go in a row because when I say `inline-block;` they aren't block elements therefore a newline won't be added after the image is rendered. Makes sense, right?!

However it doesn't work.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<img src="http://www.gaiawellnessretreat.com/sites/default/files/field/image/portfolio_8.jpg">
<img src="http://www.gaiawellnessretreat.com/sites/default/files/field/image/portfolio_8.jpg">

</div>
</body>
```

EDIT: This is **NOT** a duplicate and it is **NOT solved**.

Adding a hack like `font-size: 0` in div does not *solve* it.

Comment: 30% viewport width + 20% viewport margin + whitespace > 50% (and even at exactly 50%, there might be rounding?)

Comment: This is a duplicate of about 50 other questions asking why two div's at 50% wrap because of whitespace.

Comment: @Ry︁ whitespace from where?

Comment: @CupOfCoffee: The newline. If instead of `<img>`, you had a word, you would expect a space between them, no? That space is still there when they’re images.

Comment: @Ry︁ Horizontal space after every word? I put my spaces for words myself. Imagine how annoying it'd be if the computer tried guessing what I want to do and was inserting space and I had to use a special command to tell it this time don't do it. :)

Comment: @CupOfCoffee See my answer below. It's the whitespace from your margins.